# How to keep get location info and add to mapview when iphone in screensaving mode

Tags: iphone, gps, mkmapview

I am using

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

to keep receiving location information, then add annotation to MKMapView. It appears that it stop updating when iPhone screen in screen saving mode.

Answer (score 2):

Could you turn off the screensaving mode? You can do so by calling: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` This *should* solve your problem.